# How to solve the equation $\left \lceil {\left ( 3 \over 2 \right )}^K \right \rceil = \left \lfloor {3^K - 1} \over {2^K - 1} \right \rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

How to solve the equation $$\left \lceil {\left ( 3 \over 2 \right )}^K \right \rceil = \left \lfloor  {3^K - 1} \over {2^K - 1}  \right \rfloor$$
for $K \in \mathbb N$.

Are there any other solutions except $K=1$?

My attempt:
LHS: I used that ${2^K}\not{|}{3^K}$ {does not divide) to write
$$\left \lceil {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \rceil = 
\left \lfloor {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \rfloor + 1
$$

RHS: $$\left \lfloor {\left ( {3^K - 1} \over {2^K - 1}  \right )} \right \rfloor = 
\left \lfloor {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K + {{{\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K - 1 } \over {2^K - 1}} \right \rfloor  = 
\left \lfloor {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \left \{ {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \} + {1 \over {2^K}} {\left ( {{3^K - 2^K } \over {2^K - 1}} \right )} \right \rfloor
$$
where {...} is the decimal part of the number.
The second term is decreasing function from $\frac{1}{2}$ to 0 (in limit $K\to\infty$), so $\left \{ {1 \over {2^K}} {\left ( {{3^K - 2^K } \over {2^K - 1}} \right )} \right \} = {1 \over {2^K}} {\left ( {{3^K - 2^K } \over {2^K - 1}} \right )}$
$$\\$$

Together: $$1 = \left \lfloor \left \{ {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \} + {1 \over {2^K}} {\left ( {{3^K - 2^K } \over {2^K - 1}} \right )} \right \rfloor$$
Or as an inequality:
$$1 \le  \left \{ {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \} + {1 \over {2^K}} {\left ( {{3^K - 2^K } \over {2^K - 1}} \right )} $$

The term $\left \{ {\left ( {3} \over {2}  \right )}^K \right \}$ has form  ${r} \over {2^K} $, where $r \in \left \{ 1, 3, ..., 2^K - 1 \right \}$ (only odd numbers).
$$\\$$
And here I am stuck.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I used that $2^K$ does not divide $3^K$ to write the ceiling  as $$\left \lfloor {\left ( 3 \over 2 \right )}^K \right \rfloor + 1 = {\left ( 3 \over 2 \right )}^K -  \left \lbrace {{\left ( 3 \over 2 \right )}^K} \right \rbrace + 1$$ where {...} are decimal part of the number.

Comment: The left and right sides seem to continuously overtake each other, so $K=1$ isn't the only solution. The next couple of solutions are $K=87,89,90,91,\dots$ Due to the nature of the lower and upper whole parts, characterizing the solutions seems to be difficult. The question boils down to which power(s) of $1.5$ happen to land close to a whole number, which just comes down to "random chance".

Comment: In fact every whole number $K$ from $89$ to $996$ seems to solve the equation, and for $K=997$, the right side will be greater than the left side.

Comment: I tried this python code for K=89:`from decimal import Decimal, getcontext;import math;getcontext().prec = 100;print(math.ceil(Decimal(3**89)/Decimal(2**89)));print(math.floor((Decimal(3**89) - 1)/(Decimal(2**89) - 1)))` with result:
4700261881895380
4700261881895379
I get your result with lower precission.